# How prevent that an user change the input value?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've a website with the post, and when an user comment its I send an Ajax request.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.theFormComment', function(e){
    var data_to_send = $(this).serializeArray(); // convert form to array
    data_to_send.push({name: "cs_spotale", value: $.cookie("c_spotale") }); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/post/addComment',
        data: $.param(data_to_send),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.user_id !== data.user_to_id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/notification/addNotification",
                    data: {
                        post_id: data.the_post,
                        user_from_id: data.user_id,
                        user_to_id: data.user_to_id,
                        action: data.action,
                        cs_spotale: $.cookie("c_spotale")
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(x){
                        socket.emit('sendNotification', {data: data, type: x.type, image: x.image});
                    },
                    error: function(){}
                });
            }
            $('#comment-box-'+ data.the_post).val('');
            $("input[id='csrf_prot']").val(data.c);
            $(data.html).prependTo("#comment-" + data.the_post); 
            if(data.own !== data.username){
                socket.emit('notify', data.own, data.username); 
            }
            socket.emit('updateComment', {permaRoom: data.the_post, html: data.html});
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I saw that if I change the input value of my hidden field "post_id", the comment goes to another "post_id". There is a way to prevent this problem? Or any other idea?

Comment: Without HTML and a clearer description of the error, this problem will not be solved. @william-perron Please do not put reviews into the queue unless they address all issues with a question. Adding tags can be helpful, but there were serious problems with the formatting of the code, as well as another unneeded tag.

Comment: you don't really need submit a post id for new post since it will auto increment in your database.

Comment: @aahhaa - he wants the comments attached to a post without a user manipulating the hidden post_id (e.g; the parent of the comment).

Comment: @miken32 will do